# Error return a function using if-else shorthand in python

Tags: python, data-structures, stack

I'm trying to use this if-else shorthand inside a function:

```
def isFull(): # checks wheteher stack is full
    return True if top == (size - 1) else return False
```

But my IDE highlights the `return` saying "Expected expression".

What is wrong with the code, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Rather than tell us what your IDE thinks about the code, it's better to see what Python thinks of it when it tries executing the code. This should give you a `SyntaxError` which can be [copied and pasted as properly formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146), and properly shows the problem - [please do not upload images of errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), and please show actual errors when possible.

Comment: As for the problem, it means exactly what you are told: the part after `else` has to be an *expression*, and using `return` makes a *statement*. It is the same problem as if you had written `return 1 + return 2`, instead of `return 1 + 2`. What is written after `else` is **not** "what to do when the condition isn't met", it's "*what the value should be* when the condition isn't met". I closed this as a duplicate of the general reference question for this construction, which Python calls a *conditional expression*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't repeat `return` inside the conditional expression. The conditional expression contains expressions, `return` is a statement.

```
def isFull():
    return True if top == (size - 1) else False
```

But there's really no reason for the conditional expression at all, just return the value of the condition, since it's `True` or `False`.

```
def isFull():
    return top == size - 1
```